# programaticly create a web view and a button to return to previous view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i would appreciate a concept on How can i create a web view and set a return button so the user can return on the previous view.
I have a table view that goes to a detail view, and on the detail view i have a button that has a url link connected. Now when this button is selected it should open a web view (should it be another .xib file?) and on the web view i need a toolbar with return button that will return the detail view

i need idea on how can i do this

Thanks all

-edit
i have the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        aBook = [delegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
        // Configure the cell.
        titleValue = aBook.title;
        authorValue = aBook.author;
        urlValue = aBook.bookUrl;

        detailViewController = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController.title = titleValue; 
        detailViewController.author = aBook.author;
        detailViewController.bookUrl = aBook.bookUrl;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];

    }
```

this sets values for the detail view, so should i have the same to send the url to the web view??

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController to push the new view on the stack, then the back button will be added automaticly. You can then use an other XIB to setup the toolbar and the webview. It easy to a property to tell the webview which URL is should load.

Comment: you have misunderstood me. I have a table view(first view), then a detail view(second view) and i want to go on a web view (as a third view) from within the detail view and not to have the web view inside the detail view.

Comment: You can push the webviews viewcontroller on the stack if you are using UINavigation controller. tableview -> detailview -> webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is of-course you can create a new xib with your webviews and Toolbars  in thirdViewController and pass the url to the viewController. by touching back button you can dismiss your thirdViewController and you have the detailViewController.

or

If you really dont want to have a viewController you can create your customView design and place the controls programmatically. Then add subview the customView to your detailView. Create delegates to handle the customView Actions so that remove your customview from your detailView when back button is touched.

let me know if you have doubts

Comment: I like to try this second suggestion, but is it smart to do this. I know it's easier to  create a new nib and ViewController but this second one looks more fun and more educational. So i need to know is it going to use more memory, is it going to make my app slower or it wont do so much damage? Please advice on this mater

Comment: I prefer to take programmatically everything. Its a professional way to not to use Xibs and code every control programmatically. I really dont know about how memory operates on them. Anyhow its all matters how you code. If you handle the code with proper allocs and release your app will be stable. Read this if you have interest http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html

Comment: Thx for the advice. Hope i can contact you again here if something goes wrong :). Regards